# Blender Cycles viewport preview adjust resolution

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, resolution

I am using Blender for daily work on 2540x1440 external display.
I usually work in full screen layout and sometimes i want to preview scene in cycles. Problem is that working area is over 2000px wide and it totally waste of time to wait for each sampling iteration. My question is: Is there any kind of method to decrease the resolution on preview. Something like quality switcher in After Effects (25%,50% full etc.)

For preview purposes it could reduce the pixels like 2x 4x or 8 times. This way instead of rendering full resolution the "pixels" could be bigger allowing user to preview faster.

Thanks For Your reply!

Comment: Hello, have you tried reducing the number of samples in the viewport ? Also, if you have a compatible GPU, you can use viewport denoising and further reduce the samples

Answer (score 1):

There's an option under Render -> Performance -> Viewport

[image]

You can also define a render region with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, to keep your resolution detail but only render a portion of the viewport.